# Creating a custom exception handler for a quadratic formula solver

Tags: java, exception

Hi I'm trying to create a custom exception handler for a quadratic formula solver.  The exception handling class that I have is meant to throw the answer anytime b*b - 4*a*c is negative, and it looks like this...

```
public class NegativeDiscriminantException extends Exception {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NegativeDiscriminantException(String a){
        System.out.println(a);
        Quadratic.solver();
    }
}
```

The "Quadratic.solver();" is intended to restart the variable inquiry process from the beginning.  But here is my method to solve it from the Quadratic class...

```
static public double root( double A, double B, double C ) 
       throws IllegalArgumentException, ArithmeticException, NegativeDiscriminantException {
   try{
       if (A == 0.0) {
           throw new ArithmeticException();
       }
   }
   catch (ArithmeticException e){
       System.out.println("'A' can't be zero.");
       solver();
   }

   double disc = B*B - 4*A*C;
   try{
      if (disc < 0){
          throw new NegativeDiscriminantException("The discriminant is negative.");
      }
   }
   catch (NegativeDiscriminantException e){
      System.out.println("The discriminant is negative.");
   }
   return  (-B + Math.sqrt(disc)) / (2*A);
}
```

And I get a compiler error...

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: Unhandled exception type NegativeDiscriminantException at
>   Quadratic.solver(Quadratic.java:62) at
>   Quadratic.main(Quadratic.java:34)

I'm new with using custom exception handlers.  Could you please help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you want it to be non-checked, change type to `RuntimeException`, otherwise you need to call `root` inside a try block.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't how you use exceptions.  The idea is if there's an exceptional situation, you throw the exception and the caller of your class has to deal with it (or re-throw it).  You don't catch an exception you just threw.  So get rid of your `catch` clauses (and the surrounding `try`).

Your exception class is also bad.  It shouldn't be responsible for anything other than describing the exception.  Let the caller decide what to do.  So get rid of the call to `Quadratic.solver();`.

The compilation error is because whatever code is calling `root` needs to either catch your exceptions, or add a `throws` declaration to its signature.

Answer (score 0):

`NegativeDiscriminantException` is a checked `Exception`, so you must place any calls to a method that may throw this exception within a try/catch (or declare the caller method to throw it so it can be caught upstream).

```
try{
    root(...);
}catch(NegativeDiscriminantException e){
    e.printStackTrace();//
    Quadratic.solver();//placed here rather than within the Exception constructor
}
```

If you do not want to place calls within a try/catch (or declare the caller to throw the Exception), use an `unchecked Exception` (eg have `NegativeDiscriminantException` extend `RuntimeException`, although I do recommend reading about the '[controversy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)', and I do recommend not requiring the Exception to perform any other tasks other than defining the problem that occurred)

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your error is as @copeg mentioned that you do not handle the exception which could be thrown by the call to `Quadratic.solver()` in the constructor of your Exception.

However your usage of Exceptions is rather peculiar. Exceptions were invented to be able to handle errors at the right level and be able to bail out of nested code without using `goto` statements.

You are also calling the `solver()` method in the exception handling code which looks like it is recursing. Sooner or later this will cause your program to run out of stack space.

It would be better to handle the exceptions in the solver method so you can loop there.

```
public double solver() {
    boolean isAnswered = false;
    double answer;

    while (!isAnswered) {
        double a = askCoefficient("A:");
        double b = askCoefficient("B:");
        double c = askCoefficient("C:");

        try {
            answer = root(a,b,c);
            isAnswered = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e);
        }
    }

    return answer
}

public double root( double A, double B, double C ) throws ArithmeticException, NegativeDiscriminantException {
   if (A == 0.0) {
       throw new ArithmeticException();
   }

   double disc = B*B - 4*A*C;
   if (disc < 0){
       throw new NegativeDiscriminantException("The discriminant is negative.");
   }

   return  (-B + Math.sqrt(disc)) / (2*A);
}
```

Now the exceptions are handled where the logic can deal with them.